# Conncurency in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, functional-programming, erlang

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows:

> Write an Erlang function named print_message that takes no arguments. The function should wait to receive a message. When the message is received (it can be any Erlang term), print the message using io: format(). If 42 seconds pass without receiving a message, print a message that says “Too late.”.

The code that I wrote for the problem is down below:

```
    print_message() ->
      receive
       X -> io:format("~p~n",[X])
    after 42000 ->
       io:format("Too late ~n")
    end.
```

In my question, it says 'it can be any Erlang term'. Does using X in my code fulfill that requirement? Or do I need to use the Erlang built in function of any() as stated in the below reference manual:
https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code fulfils the requirement.  The pattern `X` matches any Erlang term.

Compare with the following, which matches only when the incoming message is a 2-tuple starting with `ok`:

```
print_message() ->
    receive
        {ok, X} ->
```

Or with this, which matches only if the incoming message is an integer:

```
print_message() ->
    receive
        X when is_integer(X) ->
```

Or with this, which matches only if the incoming message is equal to the function argument:

```
print_message(X) ->
    receive
        X ->
```

(Since the variable names are the same, this turns into a selective `receive` where all other messages are ignored.)

---

Type specs are an optional part of the Erlang language.  You could specify that your function takes an integer and returns a string:

```
-spec my_function(integer()) -> string().
my_function(N) ->
    ....
```

You could then use Dialyzer to check for type errors.

However, type specs are only used at compile time; they don't actually perform any checks at run time.  Also, they cannot be used to specify types for messages being sent or received; only function arguments and return values are covered.

Answer (score -1):

Your code fulfill the requirement.

Erlang is dynamically typed. So the type of X will be determined only on the reception of the first message, and therefore it can be any Erlang term.

To my knowledge, I don't think it is possible to specify the type of X in your code.

It exists some type specification in erlang, but it is used for the function parameters, their return values, and record definition.

these type definition can be used later for documentation or by [dialyzer](https://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html)